# lossy open stub of \$ \frac{1}{32} \lambda \$ is equivalent to?

Tags: capacitor, resistors, inductor, impedance-matching, homework

> A lossy open stub having a length of \$ \frac{1}{32} \lambda \$ , is approximately equivalent to :
>   a)A small capacitor in shunt with a small resistor
>   b)A small capacitor in shunt with a large resistor
>   c)A small inductor in shunt with a small resistor
>   d)A large inductor in shunt with a large resistor

My Approach:
$$\text{We know for a lossless line : } Z_{in}= Z_0\frac{Z_L + j Z_0 \tan(\beta l)}{Z_0 + j Z_L \tan(\beta l)}$$
$$\text{so, for a lossless open stub having a length of }  \frac{1}{32} \lambda  \text{ , is approximately equivalent to : } $$
$$Z_{in}=Z_0 \frac{1}{j \tan(\frac{\pi}{16})} \text{ , as }Z_L= \infty \text{  & } \beta= \frac{2\pi}{\lambda}$$
As \$ \tan(\frac{\pi}{16}) <1 \$ ,so \$ Z_{in} \$ is equivalent to a small capacitor
so, for a **lossy open stub** having a length of \$ \frac{1}{32} \lambda \$ , we can conclude it is equivalent to a small capacitor in series with small resistance
so what can I conclude from the options given in this question? please help...

Comment: Quick comment: I find the use of "small" and "large" in the question poor. When is a resistor or capacitor/resistor/inductor "large" or "small?

Comment: Yeah gets confusing when the large resistor approaches 1/4 wavelength long

Answer (score 1):

Completely ignoring the exact question and the proper way of doing this...

It is useful to remember that a 1/4 wave line transforms the impedance to its complex conjugate.

Which is to say, mirrors it across the centre of the smith chart.

Shorts become opens
Opens become shorts
Zin = Z0/Zout
capacitance becomes inductance

at 1/2wave it is undone: 1/2waves are transparent Zin = Zout

Very short transmission lines will be just what they are: a couple of bits of wire near each other

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/180487)

Comment: @MichealKeijzers Yes, it provides two different answers to someone who thinks about it. Answers are oblique, as it seems to me that it appropriate when someone asks an assignment question.

Comment: You are right ... I already retracted my vote some time ago (and upvoted now).

Comment: To be precise, a 1/4 wave length (180 degrees) rotation in the Smith Chart, actually finds the admittance, not the complex conjugate.

Comment: @sixcab you are right - I was sloppily using the phrase "complex conjugate" which mathematically does not change the real part at all. Any suggestions for an accurate phrase? (I assume CC is the phrase I inherited from my teacher to describe it)

Comment: Yeah, those two are very easily confused, I have... Well, that's properly the admittance, that's how I'd call it: 180 degrees (or 1/4 \$\lambda\$) rotation changes the impedance to admittance. This comes in handy because the math becomes a lot simpler (addition) when doing parallel combinations (which is what happens when adding a stub)